# Django form is not valid but no error is sent

Tags: python, django

I started to learn Django today, but I am stuck at using forms. I have created two forms: `/contact` and `/blog-new`. The form at the Contact page is working fine, but the one at `/blog-new` is redirecting me to the home page after the submission button is pressed and no information is printed in the terminal nor saved in the database.

[Code on Github](https://github.com/adrianserban95/django_test)

I appreciate if someone can explain to me what I did wrong as I cannot figure it out. Thank you!

**mysite/blog/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from .models import BlogPost

class BlogPostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'content']
```

**mysite/blog/views.py**

```
from .forms import BlogPostModelForm
def blog_post_create_view(request):
    # create objects
    # ? use a form
    # request.user -> return something
    form = BlogPostModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.save()
        form = BlogPostModelForm()
    template_name = 'form.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**mysite/blog/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**mysite/mysite/urls.py**

```
from blog.views import (
    blog_post_create_view,
)

urlpatterns = [
    ..
    path('blog-new', blog_post_create_view),
    ..
]
```

**mysite/templates/form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}



{% block content %}

{% if title %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}

<form method='POST' action='.'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you put relevant parts of your code into your question.

Comment: Hi @marke, I am sorry, I thought it's easier to upload the whole code on Github. I edited the post now with the relevant code. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to right url in `action` attribute of `form`.

```
<form action="/blog-new/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I think it's not necessary in your case but you could also refactor your view to match the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view).

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import SomeForm

def some_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = SomeForm()

    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to point to right `url` in `action` attribute of form.

That was not actually the solution but something that helped me to figure out what was wrong.

It is not necessary to point to `/blog-new/` as `.` for action will point to the same page, but I have tried with `/blog-new/` as action URL and I was surprised to see that `/blog-new/` page doesn't exist.

The bug was in **mysite/mysite/urls.py** for missing a `/`:

```
path('blog-new', blog_post_create_view),
```

It is funny (and annoying) how a symbol like `/` missing from your code will mess up everything and make you spend hours trying to find a solution as simple as that.

Thank you for your time spend to have a look over my code and try to help me!

Comment: sure thing mate :)